# How to disconnect Firebase app from Google Analytics account?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I want to add firebase project in my google analytics account say 'y' account, but my firebase project is not enabled as its saying that this project is already connected to an analytics account. In order to connect to this account you should disconnect from current analytics account. I re-check then I found there is a account say 'x' which is connected to my firebase project so I move it to trash can, but still firebase project is disabled in account 'y'. How to unlink my firebase project from 'x' account so that I can add my firebase project in my 'y' account.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to Unlink Analytics from your Firebase project:

Login to Google Firebase > Search Option on Left Side Panel > Project Overview
From there go to Project Settings > Integrations Tab > Google Analytics
Then Manage > Select the Option "Unlink Analytics from this Project".